# Button did not round on applying borderRadius: '50%' in ios

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In the android the same code rounds off the button properly. However in ios the button does not appear as rounded. Is percentage value not compatible to ios platform in react?

```
import { TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          borderRadius: '50%',
          backgroundColor: 'red',
        }}>
        <Text> Click Me</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can read on the [doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view-style-props#borderradius), `borderRadius` should a `number`, not a string as you did. You could do so:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          borderRadius: 100,
          backgroundColor: "red",
        }}
      >
        <Text> Click Me</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

Another quote from the [doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view-style-props#borderradius): “if the rounded border is not visible, try applying `overflow: 'hidden'` as well”.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like below

```
       <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          borderRadius: 100,
          backgroundColor: 'red',
        }}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use absolute values instead of relative ones, I mean something like this,

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    borderRadius: deviceHeight * 50 / 100;
  }
})
```

you can get the device height using the `Dimensions API of react-native,

```js
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';
const {height: deviceHeight} = Dimensions.get('window');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use device-independent pixel values in your **borderRadius** as per the documentation, it requires a number.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/view-style-props#borderRadius

```
borderRadius: 100
```

Also, you should consider using **Pressable** instead of **TouchableOpacity**, much more flexible, capable, and future proof

https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable